# My append() doesn't seem to be functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm sure this is a very newbie question, but I just recently started typing up some code for  a form that incorporates client side form validation. Right at the beginning of my attempt at programming the javascript/jQuery code for this, my append() method just isn't producing any visible results. I have tried getting isolating the append() statement, changing the id to class, reviewing old code in which I have appended paragraphs to divs to no avail. All suggestions and tips are very welcome.

html5 code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
        First name: <input id = "firstName" type="text" name="firstname" value="first name"><br/> 
        Last name: <input id = "lastName" type="text" name="lastname" value="last name"><br/> 
        <div class = "text"><textarea></textarea>
        <p></p> <input type="radio">Master Race Python User
        <p></p> <input type="radio">Imperial Ruby Scum
        </div>

        <div class = "languages">
        <h3>Languages Known</h3>
        <input type="checkbox">Python 
        <input type="checkbox">Ruby
        <input type="checkbox">html
        <input type="checkbox">CSS
        <input type="checkbox">Javascript
        <input type="checkbox">jQuery
        <input type="checkbox">Other
        <input type="checkbox" checked>Filthy casual
        <p><input type ="submit"></p>
        </div>
        <div id = "check">
            <p><strong><em>Check</em></strong></p>
        </div>
        <div class = "response">
            <p></p>
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
.text {
    background-color:#00ffff;
    border:solid black;
    border-radius:3%;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px
}
.languages {
    background-color:#FFFF33;
    border:solid black;
    border-radius:15%;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px;
    margin-top:10px;
}
#check {
    background-color:#ABCDEF;
    border:solid black;
    width:50px;
    margin-left:200px;
    margin-top:10px;
}

.response {
    border:solid black;
    width:190px;
    height:50px;
}
```

Javascript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".response").append("<p>"+"Nothing to do, eh?" +"</p>")
    $("#check").click(function(){
        var lastName =("#lastName").val()
        if (lastName === ""){
            $(".response").append("<p>"+"Please submit a valid entry"+"</p>")
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Seems weird it is click on the div and not the form submission.

Comment: What is the value of `lastName` in your `if` statement?

Comment: Before you do anything else, find and open the developer console built into your browser.

Comment: On that note, reading up on HTML might help too. `<p>` has more meaning than just another form of `<br />`, and making a `div` clickable as opposed to using a link/button is just weird. Also, "checking" multiple times will result in multiple error messages of the same type. We've all been there, but just a heads up OP.

Comment: Is this the actual HTML that you are using?

Comment: I will definitely have to bone up on my html concerning things like form syntax. I included the clickable div because I was more confident in my ability to deal with divs than I was with form syntax. I can see how that would look very out of place. Also, I will definitely take that advice, thanks "Guttsy."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your jQuery code is missing a `$`

This line:

```
var lastName =("#lastName").val()
```

should instead be:

```
var lastName =$("#lastName").val()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bxJaV/

Comment: holy nuggets I stared at this coding for about half an hour and I didn't notice that. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a `$` symbol in the below line. It is a typo error.

```
var lastName =("#lastName").val()
```

Instead, it should be

```
var lastName =$("#lastName").val();
```

Comment: The rest of my code isn't very processed because I couldn't continue to code while a simple append() function didn't work. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 4):

Are you including jQuery?  Your HTML code doesn't have a  tag that would load jQuery.

Try adding:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It doesn't have any `<script>` tags in fact, so I don't see where the javascript is being included at all.

Comment: Ah right, I'm used to using an editor that automatically incorporates jQuery and javascript links. Since I'm creating this from scratch in a different editor, I would need to include those links, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another problem I found is that you already set a value to #lastName:

```
<input id="lastName" type="text" name="lastname" value="last name">
```

Keep value empty and use placeholder.

```
<input id="lastName" type="text" name="lastname" value="" placeholder = "last name">
```

Comment: Be advised that `placeholder` is not supported in all browsers (i.e. 9 and below). You may have to use a polyfill for that functionality or create a simple script that will run in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Well the reason is simple, you are appending if the value for last name field is empty, but in your mark up you have set its value ="last name"

So your condition doesn't execute and hence the script doesn't append.

Just remove your value from input element in html and you are done.

I added a working code for you. Hope this helps...

http://jsbin.com/EDOJEZ/1/edit?html,output

And yes you have also forgotten `$` in your below statement

```
var lastName =$("#lastName").val();
```

Comment: Thank you defau1t, my head was definitely in the clouds when I was writing this.